# Making Whatsapp Web not needing QR-scanning

Tags: python, selenium, bots, whatsapp

I have been working on making a WhatsApp bot using selenium, but every time I run my code I have to rescan the Qr code to enter it. I found this solution in a youtube video to use options, but it doesn't work and returns an error which is `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir`

**This is my code**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\Hill\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default') 
        options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Default')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
        driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
    
        time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it was helpful. If not, just ask. This will help other programmers with the same problem and those who want to help too. So they know that there's an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically giving your Chrome-Browser two profiles. The first one, which is your profile and the second one, which is a default profile. Following steps worked for me:
Open Chrome manually and go to https://web.whatsapp.com then scan the QR-Code. Close everything and implement following code (please delete the comments in your implementation, because their syntax will cause problems ;-)):

```
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\Hill\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\') #here is no <Default>!!
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe', options=options) #selenium 4 preferes "options" -> your code is more up to date :-)
        driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
    
        time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Your way does work mine too my problem happen to me that I was opening several tabs of web WhatsApp at the same time closing them solved my problem. Thanks again

Comment: @benicamera It is raising an error of directory already in use.  `InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir`